# Subset of linear dual code

Tags: coding-theory, information-theory

Hi I need to show that

$$C_1 \subseteq C_2 \Leftrightarrow C_2^{⊥} \subseteq C_1^{\perp}$$

In guess I need to use standard form matrices for generator matrix and parity
check matrix(also parity check matrix of a code is generator matrix of its
dual code). 
C1 should have less words than C2, then more words will be orthogonal to C1. But how to put this together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$ x \in C_2^\perp \Leftrightarrow \forall y \in C_2, \langle x, y\rangle = 0\\ \Rightarrow \forall y \in C_1 \langle x,y\rangle = 0 \\
\Rightarrow x \in C_1^\perp$